# How to apply WHERE condition to EF .Include() when building up EF query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RuleValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public SharedRuleType RuleType { get; set; }
    public List<Exclusion> Exclusions { get; set; }
}

public class Exclusion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InstanceId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( "RuleId" )]
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an EF query that brings back 'all active' `Rules`, and I need it to .Include `Exclusions` for each `Rule` (if there are any) BUT only `Exclusions` that have been assigned the specified `InstanceId`. So the filtering is being done against the `Exclusions` property, rather than filtering out `Rules`.

I also have a few conditions as I build up my EF query that I need to take into consideration.

Here is my query at the moment:

```
public async Task<List<Rule>> GetRules(int instanceId, SharedRuleType ruleType, string searchTerm)
{
    using ( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        var query = context.Set<Rule>()
            .Include( r => r.Exclusions ) // *** Currently returns ALL exclusions but I only want ones where InstanceId == instanceId(param) ***
            .Where( r => r.IsActive );

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleValue.Contains( searchTerm ) );
        }

        if ( ruleType != SharedRuleType.None )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleType == ruleType );
        }

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I tried applying a .Where within the `.Include()` in an attempt to only include the relevant `Exclusions` (based on `instanceId`) but found out you can't do that. I hunted around and found some examples where people had used an anonymous type, but I couldn't get this working when building up the query piece by piece as I'm doing here.

So, I don't know how I can accomplish this as I really don't want to be returning 'every' `Exclusion` for each `Rule`, when I don't need every `Exclusion` returned.

Comment: Sometimes it's just easier to execute proper SQL.

Comment: @VinodKumar No, not yet.I don't think Vitaliy's solution below will work as it won't return 'all' rules, it will have filtered some out based on Exclusions.

Comment: At one point I was looking at this. I vaguely remember that I found it to be impossible but can't quote a source. Maybe it is best that you load the data via SQL or via separate query. In my case it was OK to write another query for the related entities that satisfy a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Include method cannot use a filter like you tried.

**Solution #1**

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allows filtering related entities.

```
public async Task<List<Rule>> GetRules(int instanceId, SharedRuleType ruleType, string searchTerm)
{
    using ( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        var query = context.Set<Rule>()
            .IncludeFilter( r => r.Exclusions.Where(x => x.InstanceId == instanceId))
            .Where( r => r.IsActive );

        // ... code ...
```

Wiki: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

**Solution #2**

Another technique is to use projection (which is what my library do under the hood)

```
public async Task<List<Rule>> GetRules(int instanceId, SharedRuleType ruleType, string searchTerm)
{
    using ( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        var query = context.Set<Rule>()
            .Where( r => r.IsActive );

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleValue.Contains( searchTerm ) );
        }

        if ( ruleType != SharedRuleType.None )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleType == ruleType );
        }


        // ToListAsync has been removed to make the example easier to understand
        return  query.Select(x => new { Rule = x,
                                        Exclusions = x.Exclusions.Where(e => e.InstanceId == instanceId)
                    })
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => x.Rule)
             .ToList();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Answer Sub-Questions #1**

*How to use ToListAsync with the previous example*

You simply have to await for the first list

```
return  (await query.Select(x => new { Rule = x,
                                Exclusions = x.Exclusions.Where(e => e.InstanceId == instanceId)
            })
     .ToListAsync())
     .Select(x => x.Rule)
     .ToList();
```

**EDIT: Answer Sub-Questions #2**

*How to perform Skip, Take, OrderBy on Rule*

You do the same as you normally do

```
return  (await query.Take(15)
                    .Skip(5)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.RuleId)
                    .Select(x => new { Rule = x,
                                            Exclusions = x.Exclusions.Where(e => e.InstanceId == instanceId)
                                })
     .ToListAsync())
     .Select(x => x.Rule)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible solutions. One question, with Solution #2, how would I incorporate .Skip, .Take and .OrderBy into the query so as to perform that filtering in the one trip to the DB, as it turns out I need this.

Comment: Also, how would I implement Solution #2 WITH the Await / Async?

Comment: On which entity (Rule or Exclusion) do you want to perform Skip, Take, OrderBy?

Comment: Rule. I would always want 'all' of the filtered Exclusions for each of the Rules returned, but I may be requesting just 10 Rules at a time (providing an offset and limit for the Skip and Take). If one of those 10 rules happened to have 50 filtered Exclusions against it, I would want all 50 Exclusions. I would also be passing in something (an enum) to identify the requested sort order to apply.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Based on your comment, you need to do request that makes LEFT JOIN for tables.

Here is variant for your new method

```
public class RuleModel
{
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Exclusion> Exclusions { get; set; }
}   

public async Task<List<RuleModel>> GetRules(int instanceId, SharedRuleType ruleType, string searchTerm)
{
    using ( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        var query = context.Set<Rule>()
            .Where( r => r.IsActive );

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleValue.Contains( searchTerm ) );
        }

        if ( ruleType != SharedRuleType.None )
        {
            query = query.Where( r => r.RuleType == ruleType );
        }

        // That statement do LEFT JOIN like:
        // FROM  Rules
        // LEFT OUTER JOIN Exclusions ON ([Rules].[Id] = [Exclusions].[RuleId]) AND ([Exclusions].[InstanceId] = @instanceId)
        var ruleExclusionQuery = query.Select(rule => new RuleModel { Rule = rule, Exclusions = rule.Exclusions.Where(e => e.InstanceId == instanceId) });
        var ruleList = await ruleExclusionQuery.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

As you can see now you can't just return Rule list if you need Exclusions too. You must return new class for that. And don't use Rule.Exclusions from result because it will make lazy request to DB and load all related exclusions.

```
.Include( r => r.Exclusions )
```

is not required anymore.

Comment: Is this not going to filter out some of my Rules though (only returning rules where there are Exclusions that match the instance)? I need 'all' rules regardless of whether they have Exclusions (and what Exclusions they are). Its just the included Exclusions (if any) that need to be filtered.

Comment: @marcusstarnes I updated code. Please, check if it match for you.

Answer (score 0):

> `Conditional include` is not yet implemented by EF team 
>   This is still a work item in EF team, you could vote [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47)

**Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities.**

If you want filter your include statement you need use projection on EF.

```
using ( var context = new MyDbContext() )
{

    Expression<Func<Rules, bool>> whereCondition;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
    {
        whereCondition= x.RuleValue.Contains(searchTerm));
    }

    var query = context.Rules
                       .Where(whereCondition)
                       .Select(x=> new 
                       {
                         rules = x,
                         exclustions = x.Exclusions.Where(secondCondition).ToList()
                       }.ToList();
}
```

If you want the expression to be work like IQuerable

You could try this, but not tested

```
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
    {
        whereCondition= x.RuleValue.Contains( searchTerm);
    }

    if ( ruleType != SharedRuleType.None )
    {
        whereCondition= x.RuleType ==ruleType;
    }
    //Ugly work around is 
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) && ruleType != SharedRuleType.None)
    {
        whereCondition= x.RuleValue.Contains( searchTerm) && x.RuleType ==ruleType;
    }
```